School is forcing me to take PE and change into their uniform. What should I do?
Assalmualaikum,
I attend an American high school and graduation requirement states we must have 4 years of physical education. I understand the requirement but, I’m a niqabi who practices full hijab, and the uniform for PE exposes the shape and curves of my body. I have reached out for a change in classes or even an alternative. This was rejected and I was told to basically “suck it up” and that this issue was only my discomfort with changing in the locker rooms. I was also told that this was a new problem I was bringing up and that no other Muslim students had complained about it. In this case what can I do?
